# PHP: Error when inserting quotation marks in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I insert a text variable in a mySQL table. Everything works fine except in the text is a quotation mark. I thought that I can prevent an error by using "mysql_real_escape_string". But there is an error anyway.

My insert statement:

```
 $insertimage= "INSERT INTO image(filename,text,timestamp,countdown) VALUES ('$filename','$text','$timestamp','$countdown')";
 mysql_real_escape_string($insertimage);
```

> The error message:
>   MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1413885955514','10')' at line 1

Comment: replace `'` with `''` before inserting into mysql

Comment: Please read [the warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is used for the single string values within the query, not for complete query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you have not correctly escaped the values you're trying to enter into the table.

Better still is to avoid the `mysql_*` function family entirely. Those functions are now deprecated and bring security risks to the table (along with other concerns).

You'd be better to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), for example:

```
$db = new PDO('param1', 'param2', 'param3');
$sql = $db->prepare( 'INSERT INTO `image` (`filename`, `text`, `timestamp`, `countdown`) 
                                   VALUES (:filename, :text, :timestamp, :countdown)' );

$sql->execute( array(':filename' => $filename, 
                     ':text' => $text, 
                     ':timestamp' => $timestamp, 
                     ':countdown' => $countdown )
);
```

Comment: While true, you did not explain the actual problem with the OP's code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was in the process of editing the answer when you commented.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape data that you are putting into the SQL so that any special characters in it don't break the SQL.

You are escaping all the special characters in the final string of SQL; even those that you want to have special meaning.

If you want to use your current approach, you would do something like this:

```
 $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($filename);
 $text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
 $timestamp = mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp);
 $countdown = mysql_real_escape_string($countdown);
 $insertimage= "INSERT INTO image(filename,text,timestamp,countdown) VALUES ('$filename','$text','$timestamp','$countdown')";
```

… but the PHP `mysql_` extension is obsolete and you shouldn't use it.

Modern APIs, such as `mysqli_` and `PDO` support prepared statements, which are a better way to handle user input. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068) covers that in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_real_escape_string($insertimage);
```

You will have to use this function to each variables before writing the query.

```
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($filename);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
$timestamp = mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp);
$countdown = mysql_real_escape_string($countdown);

$insertimage= "INSERT INTO image(filename,text,timestamp,countdown) VALUES ('$filename','$text','$timestamp','$countdown')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
  $insertimage = sprintf("INSERT INTO image(filename,text,timestamp,countdown) VALUES    ('%s','%s','%s','%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($filename), mysql_real_escape_string($text),   $timestamp, $countdown);
```

Why, because your inputs vars must be escaped before using them in sql

then execute your sql.

Comment: I'm not sure how having this code as a runnable snippet is helpful?!

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the entire query is not useful. In fact, right now, you are causing syntax errors by doing so.

You should be escaping the individual variables that you inject into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($filename);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
$timestamp = mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp);
$countdown = mysql_real_escape_string($countdown);

$insertimage = "INSERT INTO image(filename,text,timestamp,countdown) VALUES ('$filename','$text','$timestamp','$countdown')";

mysql_query($insertimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat the php variables like this:

```
$insertimage= "INSERT INTO image(filename,text,timestamp,countdown) VALUES (" . $filenamec . "," . $text . ", " . $timestamp . ", " . $countdown . ")";

with the respective single quotes in those that are text fields i.e: "... '" . $text . "' ..."
```